# (JS) creating a JSON with 2 arrays when the element of one array is the the key for the others

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

so I have these 2 arrays

```
  let answers = ['good', ' bad', 'ehh']
  let question = [
    'how are you',
    'how the weather',
    'how was the day',
    'what do you think about',
  ]
```

and I want to archive this result

```
  let final = [
    { title: 'how are you', good: false, bad: false, ehh: false },
    { title: 'how the weather', good: false, bad: false, ehh: false },
    { title: 'how was the day', good: false, bad: false, ehh: false },
    { title: 'what do you think about', good: false, bad: false, ehh: false },
  ]
```

so I want the element of answer array to be the keys of the final array,
I tried some mapping methods but didn't achieve what I wanted.

Any solution is highly appreciated

Comment: Nothing in your question has anything to do with JSON. The result you try to achieve is just a regular JavaScript array (containing regular JavaScript objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with a nested [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create the objects with `FALSE` value:

```js
const answers = [ 'good', 'bad', 'ehh' ];
const question = [
    'how are you',
    'how the weather',
    'how was the day',
    'what do you think about'
];

const res = question.map(title => ({ 
    title, 
    ...answers.reduce((p, c) => (p[c] = false, p), {}) 
}));

console.log(res)
```

Comment: thanks I'm new to this and haven't use "reduce()" before. For sure I'm gonna check it out